# Как "ужать" кнопку?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Как стандартный компонент `Button` сделать узким, но чтобы текст на них не "резался", а оставался посередине кнопки?

Comment: `android:gravity="center"`?

Comment: Это не помогает. Надо как-то установить отступы от надписи до границ кнопки, иначе надпись обрезается, а не приближается к границам при сокращении высоты кнопки.

Comment: @kaaa, кнопки плохо настраиваются. Попробуйте просто TextView использовать с `padding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью атрибутов `minWidth` и `minHeight`.

Без этих атрибутов кнопка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"/>
```

Если установить значения вышеприведенных атрибутов в `0dp`, то кнопка будет выглядеть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:text="Test"/>
```